# How to take content from html tag style with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have this:

```
<bgi align="br" bgalp="100" bgc="ccffff" hasrec="0" ialp="49" isvid="1" tile="0" useimg="1"/>
```

I simply want to take "CCFFFF" from bgc, but don't know how to do it since this information varies. Was trying with re.compile but I'm really new in this...

Comment: [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is good for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), and call the `'bgc'` attribute of the `'bgi'` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<bgi align="br" bgalp="100" bgc="ccffff" hasrec="0" ialp="49" isvid="1" tile="0" useimg="1"/>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.bgi['bgc'])
```

output:

```
ccffff
```